# Plotting - pandas - distribution in boxplots and norm distribution in histograms

Tags: plot, pandas

I'd like to add distribution to boxplot when using it with pandas dataframe like this:

```
In [52]: df = DataFrame(rand(10,5))
In [53]: plt.figure();
In [54]: bp = df.boxplot()
```

but this generates these:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Oex.png]

and I would like something like this:
[image]

is it possible using pandas? Thanks

Same with histograms, for example:

```
plt.figure()
pd.tools.plotting.hist_frame(fr_q, color="k", alpha=0.5,bins=20, figsize=fgsize)
```

and now I would like to insert "kde". It's easy for single plot, for ex.:

```
plt.figure()
a.hist(normed=True)
a.plot(kind="kde")
```

but how to added to every subplot?
Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with the first set of boxplots? the only difference here is that the second set has more outliers. fundamentally, the two plots are the same, just the data are different. Also, your final example won't run without defining `fr_q`

Comment: I wanted to show it with all measurements, not just with outliers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/fonnesbeck/5850463/raw/a29d9ffb863bfab09ff6c1fc853e1d5bf69fe3e4/3.+Plotting+and+Visualization.ipynb

here is a good resource for plotting

Comment: Thanks. I used violinplot from Seaborn.